# ¿Cómo llamarlo , para que después de haberlo registrado con el formulario Usercreationforms pueda hacer un Crud con este Usuario? Django Model User:

Tags: python, django, formularios, users-roles

**Esto es lo que tengo en mi archivo forms.py . asimismo en  las view.py estoy intentando  llamar al Model User  y tratar de modificarlo .si alguien me puede orientar como hacerlo se lo agradeceria mucho. por ultimo muestro  el formulario de UsercreationForms como lo renderizo, quiero saber como podria hacer un crud al modelo user  después de haber usado este formulario.**

**form.py**

from django import forms

from django.forms import ModelForm

from django.forms import widgets

from .models import Departamento, Location

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

```
first_name = forms.CharField()
last_name = forms.CharField()
email = forms.EmailField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name','last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1' ,'password2' )


pass
```

views.py

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

from app.forms import *

from app.models import Location,Departamento

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def modificarUser(request, id):

```
user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
usuario = get_user_model()
data={
    'form':CustomUserCreationForm(instance=User),
   
}

if request.method == 'POST':
    formulario= CustomUserCreationForm(data=request.POST, instance=user)
    if formulario.is_valid():
        formulario.save()
        return redirect(to='registro')
    data['form']=formulario

return render(request,"admin/editarUser.html", {data,'lista_Departamento':User.objects.all()})
```

**register.html**

{% extends 'app/index.html' %}

{% block contenido %}

```
    <!--================ Latest Blog Area  =================-->
    <section class="latest_blog_area section_gap">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section_title text-center">
                <h2 class="title_color">Registro</h2>
                <p>Registra una sesion.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb_30 justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <form action="" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
                    {{form|crispy}}
                    <input type="submit" value="enviar" class="btn theme_btn">
                
             </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

{% endblock contenido %}

Comment: esta mal formateado el código ... t en python es importante ...

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.